# Using mysql_real_escape_string in IN clause

Tags: php, mysql, mysql-real-escape-string

mysql_real_escape_string adds slashes to the values in IN clause and hence no values are returned. How can I send  array values that are escaped using mysql_real_escape_string() in IN clause?

Here is my code:

```
$names_array = array('dave','smith');
$names = mysql_real_escape_string("'". implode("', '", $names_array) ."'");
$sql = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE user_name IN ($names)";
$results = mysql_query($sql);
```

Query after mysql_real_escape_string changes like this:

```
SELECT * FROM user WHERE user_name IN (\'dave\', \'smith\')
```

I don't want these slashes here in IN clause. Also I don't want the values directly substituted in IN clause.
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This might do it.

```
$names = "'". implode("', '", array_map('mysql_real_escape_string', $names_array)). "'";
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `mysql_real_escape_string`; don't use the `mysql_*` functions directly at all; use [ADODB](http://adodb.sourceforge.net/) or somesuch; don't concatenate your queries in this way, use placeholders (`?`) and prepared statements. Your code should look similar to this:

```
include('/path/to/adodb.inc.php');
$DB = NewADOConnection('mysql');
$DB->Connect($server, $user, $pwd, $db);

# M'soft style data retrieval with binds
$rs = $DB->Execute("select * from user where user_names in ?",array(array('dave','smith')));
while (!$rs->EOF) {
    print_r($rs->fields);
    $rs->MoveNext();
}
```

Comment: I think *mysqli* is better than adodb?

Comment: @Shiplu as long as it's using proper procedure, I'm agnostic as to what db access library is used :); the incentive in using ADODB, PDO etc. is that you have to tweak your SQL a little if your project switches the database during development, not the php-portion.

Comment: @TomRegner Well Mysqli is an extension and adodb is a php library. For interacting with mysql mysqli would be always better. When it comes to portability PDO beats adobd. Because its an extension too.

Comment: @Shiplu there is an adodb extension too -- you simply install it, activate in in your php.ini and your adodb interactions will be tremendously faster, you don't need to touch the php-code. For any slightly serious project I think it's best practice to abstract from the used database.